# MVC 5 Routing Issue - Mutiple Routes Incorrectly Targeting Same View

Tags: c#, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have multiple routes configured, but for some reason, despite the rules addressing different Controllers and different Views, different links are routing to the same view. Please see below, I have included my RouteConfig file and example links below:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Account",
                url: "Account/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Member",
                url: "Member/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Member", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Root",
                url: "{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Details",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{u}",
                    defaults: new
                    {
                        controller = "Member",
                        action = "Details",
                        u = UrlParameter.Optional
                    }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Article",
                url: "{Home}/{Article}/{id}/{articleName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Article" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Item",
                url: "{News}/{Item}/{id}/{itemName}",
                defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Item" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**Links**

```
http://localhost:11508/Home/Article/2/Participate
http://localhost:11508/News/Item/2/Second-Test
```

As so can see, the links and rules are most certainly unique but for some reason the Item rule is being ignored, it is simply passing Id 2 to the Home/Article view.

Comment: Register your route before the default route and try again.

Comment: Here's a tip: use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), it also works for MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include controller / action names in brackets - just pass them as is, so that path can be matched. Your last two routes should look like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Article",
            url: "Home/Article/{id}/{articleName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Article" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Item",
            url: "News/Item/{id}/{itemName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Item" }
        );
```

Also, it is good to place such specific routes **before** any other routes, not **after** default routes.

**UPDATE**

Basically it should be separate question, but it is easier to just answer it here.

From comment:

> how I can get `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details?u=testuser` to be routed to `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details/testuser` instead of a showing parameter.

1. Create controller action which accepts this parameter, like this one:

   ```
   public ActionResult Details(string u, ...)
   {
       var model = new ...
       ...
       return View(model);
   }
   ```
2. Register route, which accepts `u` parameter as URL part, like this one

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "MyRoute",
           url: "Member/Details/{u}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Member", action = "Details", u = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   ```

   Here `{u}` actually declares parameter name, and how it should be used (parsed / rendered) inside URL.
3. Render link to the URL like this one:

   ```
   <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Member", new {u = "testuser"})">linktext</a>
   ```

In all these steps, `u` is that name of parameter which you will use.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked a treat, now I just need to figure out how I can get `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details?u=testuser` to be routed to `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details/testuser` instead of a showing parameter.

Comment: @iggyweb answer is not short enough so I've updated post with answer. I think you need to read about routing and how it works in MVC to understand it better.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, my controller is already accepting the variable `u` which is `public ActionResult Details(string u)` the url `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details?u=testuser` works but I would like it to render as `http://localhost:11508/Member/Details/testuser`, I've modified the route and link but still no joy. My link was `@Html.ActionLink(item.UserName, "Details", new { Controller = "Member", u = item.UserName })`

Comment: @iggyweb That should work, so I think you need separate question for that with more details.

Answer (score 1):

The Mapping takes the first matching rule.
The "Item"-Route would never be used because the Article-Root will catch all request that could match "Item"-Route.
Check the order of the routes AND delete the {} surrounding news.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Item",
            url: "News/Item/{id}/{itemName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "Item" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the order in which you are registering your routes. The rule is that you should register them from the most specific to the least. In other words, your "default" route(s) should be the very last.

With how you have it right now, MVC gets a hit on your default route, because your `item` route matches that, so once it hits on that, it stops looking for other routes and uses it.

Move your `item` route up to the top of your `RegisterRoutes` method and it should work fine.

Comment: I tried moving routes `Root` and `Default` to the end and ended up with Http 400 Bad Request Error. So tried moving `Article` and `Item` up to the top just below `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` but again the Item route is being disregarded.